# Binding in Xamarin Sidebar Menu (how to bypass naming convention)

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I've used Xamarin Sidebar to make SideMenu for iOS (similar to NavigationDrawer in Android). Problem is that in Android NavigationDrawer is just part of Activity xml file so it calls for one ViewModel. In Xamarin Sidebar however it is done in three different ViewControllers (RootVC initializing  ContentVC and MenuVC).

Lets suppose that we have SomeViewModel class. To do the trick with Sidebar we have to make SomeView (:MvxViewController being RootVC), and two others SomeContentView and SomeMenuView. So now we have to bind Content and Menu views to SomeViewModel. Problem is that they don't follow naming convention so I cannot write

```
var contentView = CreateViewControllerFor(SomeViewModel); 
var navigationView = CreateViewControllerFor(SomeViewModel);
```

Is there any way to make (in this example) **SomeContent**View bindable to **Some**ViewModel ?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MvxFragmentsAndHamburger will help.

Comment: This problem was produced by teribble missfortune. It happens that ios UILabel.SizeToFit() fails when it comes to data binding. So I couldn't get any of my properties appear on the screen. All you have to do is to set the DataContext. Thnx on help anyway.